# List of Combination

Tags: data-preprocessing

Hallo I have this problem about some data that i wish to reconcile. I do not really know the specific statistical software that could allow me to generate the list of combinations that add up to a particular sum. Any idea of the best solution to this problem?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you mean permutations, subsets, combinations with/without repeatings? Please elaborate...

Comment: Yes, am exactly hoping to get a subset of combinations without repetitions. I wish to upload the data in excel so that i can demonstrate. But i do not see that option. I have the list of transactions that are combined to form a particular figure. However, the numbers are too many and mixed up. So finding the particular subsets is a challenge. I would really appreciate if could find a way of sharing an excel with these data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your question is really connected to Cross Validated. However in Stack Overflow this question has been asked a number of times, e.g.,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316479/combination-without-repetition-of-n-elements-without-use-for-to-do

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. I was somehow hoping this solution could be solved by some statistical software. Thank you for the information about stack overflow though.